# How do I make it so when I print a Python list it doesn't have the single quotes and brackets with each item when I print the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so I have been coding Python and when I run this code

```
names = ["Harry", " Ron", "Hermione"]
print(names)
# output: ['Harry', ' Ron', 'Hermione']
```

How do I make it so it doesn't have the [] and the ' '.
Thanks!

Comment: can you clarify in text _exactly_ what the output is you're looking for? The answer could be as simple as `print(*names)`

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon you want the output to be, you can use

```
print(*names,sep=' ')
```

by default sep value is ' '. If you want to print all elements in new line then pass '\n' as sep.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(", ".join(names))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways come to mind if you want to maintain the comma separator:

```
print(*names,sep=",")
```

or

```
print(','.join(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
names = ["Harry", " Ron", "Hermione"]

for name in names:
    print(name, end=" ")
```

Comment: there won't be a newline after the final name. If you're gonna do this then you'll want a `print()` after the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
print(', '.join([n.strip() for n in names]))
```

or (tks to @Ryan Haining)

```
print(*[n.strip() for n in names])
```

Comment: you don't need `[]` inside the join like that, it generates an extra list. remove them and you get a generator expression `', '.join(n.strip() for n in names)`

Comment: thought you wanted to remove the space in front of " Ron".... if you don't care about it then no need for strip().